# using mysql inner join with three tables, cannot display result in php output

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am joining three tables, I prefixed each column name with the table so each column name is distinct. The query gives me the result I want in MySQL but when I attempt to echo it out specific field name in php, they won't display. I have tried both `mysqli_fetch_arrary()` and `mysqli_fetch_assoc()`.

```
<?php
$query  = "SELECT * ";
$query .= "FROM plans ";
$query .= "INNER JOIN plans_items ON plans.plan_id = plans_items.fk_plan_id  ";
$query .= "INNER JOIN items ON plans_items.fk_item_id = items.item_id ";
                    $item_set = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
                    confirm_query($item_set);
?>
<ul class="pages">
<?php 
    while($single_item = mysqli_fetch_array($item_set)) {
?>
    <li><?php echo "Name :" .$row['item_name']. "."; ?></li>
<?php
    }
?>
<?php mysqli_free_result($item_set); ?>
</ul>
```

Comment: Do a `var_dump($single_item);` inside of your `while` loop to see if the array is populated as you expect it to be.

Comment: you're simply assuming your query succeeded. changing fetch styles won't help if the query failed or matched 0 rows. `if ($item_set === false) { die(mysqli_error($connection)); } var_dump($item_set->rowCount());`.

Comment: I assume the query works in the mysql command line client and gets the data you want?

Comment: Yes, I ran the query in MySQL query window, I get the results I wanted. Var_dump shows im returning 12 fields as I am expecting